# Disable autocomplete on focus on choice items

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jQuery UI Autocomplete plugin on a textarea

What I want is the textarea content should not be modified when the user hovers on the autocomplete list

This means, if the user scrolls though the list or hovers on the options, the textarea contents should not change. The change should occur only on selection of the option.

Comment: i think by default, autocomplete does not modify the input content while hovering on the list.

Comment: @Jetoox: If you use the keyboard to navigate through the list of suggested items, the contents of the `input` will be replaced.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$("#my_textarea").autocomplete({
    source: mySource,
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault() // <-- prevent the textarea from being updated.
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/hJ9sA/